# Loading jsGrid Dropdown by data from another jsGrid

Tags: jsgrid

How can we load data in jsgrid (dropdown), when from another jsgrid which is filled updated by user.

Answer (score 1):

Get items from the first grid:

```
var items = $("#grid1").jsGrid("option", "data");
```

And set them when needed (e.g. in `onItemUpdated` and `onItemInserted` callbacks) with [fieldOption](http://js-grid.com/docs/#fieldoptionfieldnamefieldindex-optionname-optionvalue) method.

```
$("#grid2").jsGrid("fieldOption", "mySelectField", "items", items)
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be the chosen answer. My select list is using an Id as the valueField in grid2 so I'll need to retrieve and populate that as well.